# JavaScript array filter returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to understand what rules apply to array mapping when using different syntax/method of writing a function.

```
    var MyArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

function removeEveryOther(array){
    array.filter(function(value, index) {
        return index % 2 === 0;
    })
}

var Filtered = MyArray.removeEveryOther;
console.log(Filtered);
```

I want to remove every other element from an array using filter. For some reason the above returns undefined, why?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, and is not being called.

Comment: `MyArray` does not have a property called `removeEveryOther` as you call in your code. Probably you wanted to call instead like `removeEveryOther(MyArray)`.

Comment: There are a few things you might have missed. You are callin MyArray.removeEveryOther directly. Have you added it to the prototype ?

Comment: after filter, you need to return the filtered data.

Comment: `return array.filter(....`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to return the `.filter()` method result here like:

```
function removeEveryOther(array) {
  return array.filter(function(value, index) {
    return index % 2 === 0;
  })
}
```

Otherwise what you are doing is mainly returning undefined like:

```
function removeEveryOther(array) {}
console.log( removeEveryOther([]) )  //=> returns "undefined"
```

Then you need to properly call the `removeEveryOther()` function by passing the array like:

```
var Filtered = removeEveryOther(MyArray);
console.log(Filtered);
```

**Demo (ES5):**

```js
var MyArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

function removeEveryOther(array){
    return array.filter(function(value, index) {
        return index % 2 === 0;
    })
}

var Filtered = removeEveryOther(MyArray);
console.log(Filtered);
```

**Demo (ES6):**

```js
var MyArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]
function removeEveryOther(array){
  return array.filter((value, index) => index % 2 === 0);
}

var Filtered = removeEveryOther(MyArray);
console.log(Filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to return your filtered array like this:

```
return array.filter(function(value, index) {
        return index % 2 === 0;
})
```

Second, when you call your function you need to call it like this:

```
var Filtered = removeEveryOther(MyArray);
```

Overall, your code should look like this:

```
var MyArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

function removeEveryOther(array){
    return array.filter(function(value, index) {
        return index % 2 === 0;
    })
}

var Filtered = removeEveryOther(MyArray);
console.log(Filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **MDN** [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

You have to pass a `callback` function as the first argument of the `filter`.

Your code should look like this

```js
var MyArray = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"];
var filtered = MyArray.filter((item, index) => index % 2 === 0);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const MyArray = ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4'];

const removeEveryOther = array =>
  array.filter((value, index) => index % 2 === 0);

const Filtered = removeEveryOther(MyArray);
console.log(Filtered);
```